# In order for me to update my apps I have to have payment info. How do I fix this

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

So I tried the thing in the settings when you go to iTunes and App Store then go to payment info and click none. But for my iphone5 there is no none on the payment info. HELPPPPP

Comment: Update what apps? did you purchase them?

Comment: Help us help you by explaining what you want to do. What "thing" precisely are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I want to not have to have a payment info when I update and download apps

Comment: I did not purchase the

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me multiple times(on different accounts that is), and although I don't really remember precisely what I did, there was an option to proceed without putting in any credit card details, and if I remember correctly, it was even set as the default option. I am unable to replicate this again, so I can't really say for sure now, but you don't really have to put in any further details, just look for the option that says something like "None" or something along those lines and click next. That should do it for you and then Apple won't bug you asking for payment details again, or at least its only ever happened once for me.